# What does #define without assignment assign to in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have often seen code like

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
#define HEADERFILE_H
// some declarations in
// the header file.
#endif
```

I want to know what `#define HEADERFILE_H` define `HEADERFILE_H` to?

I tried doing

```
cout<<HEADERFILE_H<<endl;
```

but I am getting

```
error: expected expression
```

Comment: If you `#define TEST` and you later use it somewhere, `TEST` is replaced with nothing. E.g.: `int x = foo(TEST);` is equivalent to `int x = foo();`. As @ThomasJager pointed out, in this case the "empty" `#define` is used to include the header only once.

Comment: You seem to be switching languages mid-stream.  You talk of C, but the code is C++.  Which is it?

Comment: I wanted to use printf but didn't know the type, so I used cout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `define` preprocessing directive has the form `# define identifier preprocessing-tokens`, ending with a new-line character. The `preprocessing-tokens` is a list of zero or more preprocessing tokens. It may be empty, that is, it may have zero tokens. This means, that when the `identifier` is encountered in a place where macro replacement occurs, it will be replaced with nothing.<sup>1</sup>

Tests of the form `#ifdef identifier`, `#ifndef identifier`, or  `defined identifier` in a `#if` or `#elif` directive test whether `identifier` is defined or not. If it was not defined (or its definition was removed with the `#undef` directive), then the test indicates it is not defined. If it was defined, then the test indicates it was defined, even if the definition is for zero tokens.

A definition with zero tokens is different from no definition at all, and `defined identifier` will evaluate as true for the former and false for the latter.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup>  If the list does have tokens, then `identifier` will be replaced with those tokens and `#` and `##` operators among them will be applied. A preprocessing token is largely an identifier (like `foo34`), a constant (like `3`, `4u`, or `1.8e4`), one of the C operators or special characters (like `*` or `+=`), or certain other components of the C language.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the preprocessor maintains a map of identifier to preprocessor tokens. The only thing in my case is the preprocessor tokens is empty? Also #undef removes from the map?

Comment: @Heroman: It is up to each C compiler (or other C implementation) to manage its data in some way. The C standard just says what behavior results from using macro replacement and `#define` directives, not how a compiler has to implement them. Most compilers likely maintain a map or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This is a language idiom (I will comment it):

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
```

Between this, and the last `#endif` everything is included in compilation, but only if `HEADERFILE_H` has not been defined before.

```
#define HEADERFILE_H
```

The first thing we do in the block is to `#define` the identifier, so next time we find this fragment again later, the contents between `#ifndef` and `#endif` will not be `#include`d again (because of the identifier declaration).

```
// some declarations in
// the header file.
```

this block will be included only once, even if you `#include` this file several times.

```
#endif
```

and this marks the end of the protected block.

It is common to include some file that, indeed, `#include`s another, and that file includes another, leading to a point in which you don't know which files have been included and which don't.  This phrasing allows you to be protected, and to be able to `#include` the same file several times (normally you cannot, as some definitions cannot be repeated in the same compilation unit, e.g. declarations) the lines above will include the contents and define the identifier, making next inclussions (that are effectively done) not to include the contents, as the identifier appears as `#definen` in second and ulterior times.

Answer (score 0):

It actually defines "nothing else than itself". That is: you may define a macro without assigning it a specific value. Since you can check if a given macro is defined or not, you therefore can ask for the simple "existence" of a given macro.

This is useful to indicate a context (for example, if you're compiling for a given OS) and/or the availability of some resources.

In this particular example, this is a called a "guard": it will define itself if this hasn't been done first before, as well as including the rest of the file, which is totally embedded in the `#ifdef … #endif` clause.

This is used to implement a kind of `require_once`, that is something that will be included if needed, but not multiple times. This is required when you are defining functions or declaring variables at a global scope, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "nothing else than itself". Is it a numerical value? I want to know the internals.

Comment: `#define HEADERFILE_H` does not define `HEADERFILE_H` to be “itself,” so it does not define it to be “nothing else than itself.” It defines `HEADERFILE_H` to be the empty sequence of preprocessor tokens.